# C# Paint Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a simple painting program with c# that draws on a panel, but whenever I change the color of the Pen all the other lines change to that color too. So if I draw 3 lines with the color black and then change the color to red with the colorDialog and draw another line, the older lines also change to red. What I want is for the lines to keep their original color. Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
     Point current = new Point();
     Point old = new Point();
    List<List<Point>> curves = new List<List<Point>>();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 5f);
     Graphics g;
    Bitmap surface;
    Graphics graph;
    Color color;

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        p.SetLineCap(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashCap.Round);
        surface = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(surface);
        panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Pictures\Saved Pictures\download.jpg");
        panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        old = e.Location;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            
            points.Add(e.Location);
           
            current = e.Location;
            g.DrawLine(p, old, current);
            old = current;
        }
    }

    private void undo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curves.RemoveAt(curves.Count - 1);
        panel1.Invalidate();
       
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       
        for(int i = 0; i<curves.Count; i++)
        {
            
            e.Graphics.DrawCurve(p, curves[i].ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (points.Count > 1) curves.Add(points.ToList());
        
        points.Clear();
        //panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            color = colorDialog1.Color;
            p = new Pen(color, 5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Among the various things wrong, you only have one pen, `p` used to draw everything.  Since it can only be one color at a time...

Comment: Remove this: `g = panel1.CreateGraphics();` and all other things you never use (as `graph = Graphics.FromImage(surface);`). Do all the drawing in the Paint event of your *canvas* (possibly use a PictureBox as drawing surface). Then, you have to store your drawings in a collection of class objects that describe the drawing. The Color of the Pen to use is one of these details (as the Pen size, it shape, the Brush, if you're also filling the shape etc.). If you want to use a specific Pen, Brush etc. for each shape.

Comment: And it's a wonderful opportunity for some polymorphism, to have a generic Shape class that has an abstract DrawYourselfOnThisCanvas method, implemented concretely differently triangle and rectangle...

Comment: You will need to store more than just the points. As Pens have a Color but also quite a few other Poperties like Width and then some you could either create a more complex type called maybe `DrawAction` or create a Dictionary<int, Pen> and store all Pens you need there and add a `List<int> penIndices`. - A couple of [post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+DrawAction) with more comments on the topic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I solved the problem by making a class that contains the points and the Pen and then creating an object of that class every time a line is drawn after that in the paint function it goes through the list of the objects and redraws every line with the corresponding color.